# Paint request not executed on working with two JPanels on a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to work with two JPanel on a single Jframe . I am adding them to frame using the container . so when i add first Jpanel to frame, the Paint Component method is called but when i add second JPanel to frame , the paint Component method is not called by the JVM.

here is the code ,

```
public class Frame {

     public Frame() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
      }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
         JFrame gui = new JFrame();
         gui.setTitle("Chain Reaction ;-) ");
         gui.setSize(650,650);
         gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
         gui.setVisible(true);  
         Container Pane = gui.getContentPane();
         Panel1 myPane1 = new Panel1(Pane); 
    }
 }
```

here i am adding Panel1(JPanel) object to JFrame in constructor. I am passing container reference to constructor .

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    Container myPane;

    public Panel1(Container myPane) {
        this.myPane = myPane;
        myPane.add(this);
        addMouseListener(new event(myPane));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(200, 200, 400, 400);
    }

    public class event extends MouseAdapter {

        Container myPane;

        public event(Container myPane) {
            this.myPane = myPane;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Panel2 myPanel2 = new Panel2(myPane);
        }
    }
}
```

(Panel1 class has event class which listens for mouse click ,when mouse is clicked it Creates object of Panel2)

```
public class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    Container myPane;

    public Panel2(Container myPane) {
        this.myPane = myPane;
        myPane.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(400, 400, 200, 200);
    }

}
```

Panel2 receives reference Container through constructor , and then draws a rectange, this paint request is not being called by JVM .

Help me . what i should do now ?

Answer (score 3):

By default a JFrame uses a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the frame and don't specify a constraint the component is added to the CENTER. Only one component can be added to the center, so only the last component is displayed.

However, when you add a component to a visible GUI you also need to invoke `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the panel that you add the component to so the layout manager can be invoked.

In your case you don't invoke revalidate() so the second panel has a size o (0, 0) so there is nothing to be painted.

if you do invoke revalidate() then the second panel will have a size but now the first panel won't be painted.

You need to redesign you app or use a different layout to get your desired effect.

Also, in your main() method you should be adding the panel to the frame BEFORE you make the frame visible.

Comment: I wanna paint using both panels (only one at a time) . Now what should i do , should i add revalidate in both panels ?. help me

Comment: @RamVijay `I wanna paint using both panels (only one at a time)`. Then you need to use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).